# mongo eve for different users display different collections

Tags: mongodb, collections, eve

I am using eve to read different databases from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30839991/9622530) but I still have a question using 'Auth-driven Database Access'.

I have three databases named db1(has one collection named collection1),

db2(has one collection named collection2),

db3(has one collection named collection3).

and my setting.py has

DOMAIN = {

```
   'collection1': {schema: schema1},

   'collection2': {schema: schema2},

   'collection3': {schema: schema3},
```

}

When I consume the API:

`curl -H "Authorization: Basic [user_a:passwd(base64)]" -i http://127.0.0.1:5000`

I get the results of all collections:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "child": [
      {
        "href": "collection1",
        "title": "collection1"
      },
      {
        "href": "collection2",
        "title": "collection2"
      },
      {
        "href": "collection3",
        "title": "collection3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But how can I achieve that different users are showed different collections, e.g. user A can only see collection1, user B can only see collection2?